# Update UI from AsyncTask and handle properly screen rotate

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler

This code doesn't works when rotate screen.
I try to use Handler but messages are dispached to previous Activity(before rotate) and to new Activity.

¿How can a thread send messages to new Activity?
Please doesn't suggest avoid to rotate screen.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text;
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("HELLO");

        layout.addView(text);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            text.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text"));
        }

        setContentView(layout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("text", text.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new CounterTask().execute();
    }

    public class CounterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    publishProgress("Hello " + i);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            String str = values[0];
            text.setText(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the `AsyncTask` in a retained fragment.

```
public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {
    private Callback mCallback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mCallback = (Callback) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement TaskFragment.Callback");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        mCallback = null;
    }

    public void execute(){
        new CounterTask().execute();
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onTaskUpdate(String value);
    }

    public class CounterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    publishProgress("Hello " + i);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            if(mCallback != null) {
                String str = values[0];
                mCallback.onTaskUpdate(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, implement the callback in your activity and add the fragment via the fragment manager.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements
        TaskFragment.Callback {
    private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "task_fragment";

    private TaskFragment mTaskFragment;

    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("HELLO");

        layout.addView(text);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            text.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text"));
        }

        setContentView(layout);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

        if(mTaskFragment == null){
            mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(mTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("text", text.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mTaskFragment.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskUpdate(String value) {
        text.setText(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html). It will handle all rotations and lifecycle events of your activity/fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some configuration to prevent the recreating of activity when screen rotated, then everything's ok since there's only one instance of your activity.

Add the flowing line to your activity label in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

and this method to you SampleActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // when screen rotated, this method will be called instead of onCreate
}
```